# Error x is not numeric while using corrplot(df_train) or using cor(df_train) in R programming . Even though everything I have converted to numeric

Tags: r

I am getting error x is not numeric while using `corrplot(df_train)` or using `cor(df_train)`. Even though everything I have converted to numeric using `df_train$is_fraud<- as.numeric(as.character(df_train$is_fraud))`. The 10 columns that I have in my data I have converted every column but still getting error.

I converted every column to numeric but still that is issue is there.

Comment: When posting, you must post a small, reproducible example of your input data.

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.